# How do you disable highlight prorperty name on vscode typescript (or all in general)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I disable those `name:` highglight? It is really annoying, but I didn't know how to disable it.

[image: property highlight]

Comment: `editor.selectionHighlight`, have you tried typing `selection` in the settings GUI

Comment: Thats not a selection hightlight actually, (I tried it). I think this is new fature because I use insiders branch @rioV8

Comment: then find out the TextMate scope of the `name:`, or look at the semantic highlighting settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings:

```js
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": false,
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16221#issuecomment-879538951